# Input in the same line with space.

Tags: c++, c, input

I need to do a program and the input is a set of data with 6 lines and with 3 numbers separated by spaces, with a 'c' or with a 'f' in the last line:

```
input:
4 5 6
7 8 9
7 8 9
4 5 6
7 8 9
7 8 9
c
4 5 6
7 8 9
7 8 9
4 5 6
7 8 9
7 8 9
c
4 5 6
7 8 9
7 8 9
4 5 6
7 8 9
7 8 9
f
```

If the last letter after the 6 lines is a c, continue with other 6 lines and if it is a f, finish.

I intend with:

```
int main(){

char a;
int triangulo[6][3];
do{
    for(int i=0; i<6; i++){
            cin>>triangulo[i][0]>>triangulo[i][1]>>triangulo[i][2];                    
    }

    cin>>a;  
}while(a != 'f'); 


system("pause");
}
```

But it now works, can you help me.
Because I do not how can I recieve 3 numbers in the same line, separated by spaces and receive very much data set.

And another question. For example, if the user write c 7 times, I need create an array for each data set??

```
input:
4 5 6
7 8 9
7 8 9
4 5 6
7 8 9
7 8 9
c
4 5 6
7 8 9
7 8 9
4 5 6
7 8 9
7 8 9
c
4 5 6
7 8 9
7 8 9
4 5 6
7 8 9
7 8 9
f
```

And if I have to sum each array and the sum is my output, I need to create an array for each data set??

```
output
126
126
126
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work for reading three digits.

```
cin>>triangulo[0] >> triangulo[1] >> triangulo[2];
```

However, if you are reading numbers (1, 2, 3, 18, 33, 418 or some such), you probably want to use `int triangulo[3];` instead. And if you actually want to store 6 sets of three numbers, you will need a two-dimensional array:

```
int triangulo[6][3];

...

        cin>>triangulo[i][0] >> triangulo[i][1] >> triangulo[i][2];
```

Comment: No i intent but i write the six lines, later a f, and the program never finish

Comment: Can you word that in a different way, because I don't understand what you are asking/saying.

Comment: Try making your array variable `int triangulo[...];` instead of `char triangulo[...];` - with char, it will accept the space between the digits as input, so you will be out of sync, and it's probably on a different set of 18 "numbers" by the time you type in your 'f'.

Answer (score 0):

try this?

```
int main(){

    char a;
    int triangulo[3];
    int sum=0;
    do{
        for(int i=0; i<6; i++){
            cin>>triangulo[0] >> triangulo[1] >> triangulo[2];
            sum=sum+triangulo[0]+triangulo[1]+triangulo[2];
        }

        cin>>a;  
    }while(a != 'f'); 

    cout<<sum;

    system("pause");
}
```

If you wish to store all the arrays, you can make the user to input a number(how many arrays will there be) before input the arrays and allocate the memory using `new`.

Comment: How is this different from the original question?

Comment: Yes, But my main problem is: i insert the six lines, later a 'c' to continue, later, other 6 lines. and i need create an array for each time that i insert to continue??, for example if i write the 6 lines later a 'c', later other 6 lines later 'f', i need create 2 arrays?. Because i need do an operation. and print a output.

Comment: @AlexanderOvalle If you want to print after all the arrays have been inputed, then yes. Or you can print an array after each input. If you don't know how many input arrays you may have, you should use `new` to dynamically allocate memory.

Comment: I need print the sum, i need create an array for each array?

Comment: Because when the program begins i do not How many times the user will write 'c'?

Comment: @AlexanderOvalle Then you must use `new`, wait for me to edit my answer.

Comment: @AlexanderOvalle Wait! If you only need to print the sum, you can add them each time you input an array. So you won't need to store all the number. Is that OK?

Comment: And how function with new?